# Service error: Spreadsheets using isblank()

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, spreadsheet

I have a big problem since 2 days, my functiun doesn't work anymore :/
"Service error: Spreadsheets" at "if (cell.isBlank())"

```
    function miseEnForme(){
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var feuilleAdm = classeur.getSheetByName("SuiviAdministratif");

  var lastRow;
  for (var row = 3; row < 1000; row++) {
    var cell=feuilleAdm.getRange(row,3);
    if (cell.isBlank()) {
      lastRow =row;
      break;
    }
  }

  for (var i =3; i<lastRow;i++){
   if (feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="RS" || feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="RP" || feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="RD")
     feuilleAdm.getRange("SuiviAdministratif!A"+i+":AB"+i).setBackground("red");

   if (feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="C")
     feuilleAdm.getRange("SuiviAdministratif!A"+i+":AB"+i).setBackground("#00ff00");

   if (feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="O")
     feuilleAdm.getRange("SuiviAdministratif!A"+i+":AB"+i).setBackground("white");
  }
}
```

Is it my fault or Google have change something?
How to solve the problem?

Thanks

Comment: Does it not run at all or does it throw this error after few iterations? Could you Log row (Logger.log(row)) to figure which row gives the problem and check to see if that row has a data that is different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout this [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/adwords-scripts/vQWY-gT-UIY).  I'm guessing that there's nothing wrong with the code.  It's just that Google Servers are trying to entice you into using a more batch oriented approach.  For example you could get all of your data with one call to `var datA=sheet.getDataRange().getValues();` and then you would have all of your data in a 2 dimensional array.  It would be easier for Google servers to handle your process and it would perform much better for you. I'll take a copy of your code and see if I can simplify it for you.  Perhaps you could give me an idea of what your data looks like.

I haven't tested this code.  If you can share some of your data with me I'll be glad to do so.  This should be pretty close though.  I tried to follow the same basic approach that you were using so you could figure out what's happening a little easier.

```
function miseEnForme()
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var sht = ss.getSheetByName("SuiviAdministratif");
  var datrng = sht.getDataRange();
  var datA = datrng.getValues();//datA is a 2 dimensional array starts at zero
  var lastCol = datrng.getLastColumn();

  for(var i=2;i<datA.length;i++)
  {
    if(datA[1][i] == ("RS" || "RP" || "RD"))
    {
      sht.getRange(i+1,1,1,lastCol).setBackground('#ff0000');
    }
    if(datA[1][i] == "C")
    {
      sht.getRange(i+1,1,1,lastCol).setBackground('#00ff00');
    }
    if(datA[1][i] == "O")
    {
      sht.getRange(i+1,1,1,lastCol).setBackground('#ffffff');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As Cooper say, your code is not the problem here. 
Otherwise, a little workaround will help you :

```
function miseEnForme(){
  var classeur = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var feuilleAdm = classeur.getSheetByName("SuiviAdministratif");

  // getLastRow() return the value of the last row used in the sheet
  var lastRow = feuilleAdm.getLastRow();

  for (var i =3; i<lastRow;i++){
   if (feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="RS" || feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="RP" || feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="RD")
     feuilleAdm.getRange("SuiviAdministratif!A"+i+":AB"+i).setBackground("red");

   if (feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="C")
     feuilleAdm.getRange("SuiviAdministratif!A"+i+":AB"+i).setBackground("#00ff00");

   if (feuilleAdm.getRange("B"+i).getDisplayValue()=="O")
     feuilleAdm.getRange("SuiviAdministratif!A"+i+":AB"+i).setBackground("white");
  }
}
```

More about the getLastRow method : https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getLastRow()